# Related papers about finding longest vector(maximum in magnitude) as subset sum from given set of 2d vectors

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, research

Given a set of 2D vectors. Find maximum magnitude of sum of a subset of the set.

I want to do my undergrad thesis on this topic. Can anyone suggest me some existing papers related to this topic or its real life use cases? I need research papers specifically.

Comment: (First algorithm idea: Order vectors by angle. Find "180 sum". Use a *moving window* through one full circle.)

Comment: @greybeard can you suggest any previous works and papers related to this topic? I have multiple solutions for this problem. But probably I need some background studies and have to go through previous works.

Comment: (There is a CS@SE tag [reference-request](/tags/reference-request/info) for *requesting papers in the literature on specific, narrow issues*.)